# ClassiC ASP inside a IFRAME in Aspx

Tags: asp.net, iframe, asp-classic

I have a scenario in which I am loading a separate classic-ASP application into an IFRAME which I have programmatically embedded into an ASP.Net web form. This external application uses session variables extensively, however, when it navigates from one page to another, it loses the session variables. Any suggestions?

Comment: This needs more clarification.  Are you expecting the ASP session and the ASP.NET session to be the same?  Are both applications hosted on the same domain?  Have you inspected the session cookies to make sure the same session ID is being sent/received between requests, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Session will be lost if you the asp page is another domain. You can solve this by adding p3p header to your asp pages.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540926/ie7-iframe-blank-page) which I asked some time ago. Alternatively you can check this [blog post](http://www.codegeeks.net/ie7-iframe-and-cookie-hell).

Comment: Yes please check the post and question.