# Cross Domain Cookies with IFrame in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, iframe, cookies, cross-domain

I had a client's requirement for opening a another domain link in Iframe. This thing works fine with Firefox, Chrome but in Internet Explorer its giving error that cookies are not enabled. When I directly open that link it work fine with IE, but with IFrame its not the same case. I did some search on Google and didn't find a proper answer for it. I just want to confirm is there any coding fault from my side? I also found this solution for the problem

In PHP:

```
header ( "p3p:CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

But its not working on my case. I am not sure where should I put this, because I can change the code of my website if require. But I can't change the Iframe site, Since we are not the owner.

This project is built in PHP.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I asked a similar question few years back. Plz check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540926/ie7-iframe-blank-page

Comment: if iframe is the answer, the question was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The subframe's cookies are blocked by the browser's Cookie Privacy feature.

That subframe (the one setting the cookies) must send a P3P statement indicating how the cookies will be used in order for the browser to accept them.

Specifying the P3P statement in the *outer* frame is not sufficient and will not help anything.

Answer (score -2):

Are you runnig IE in protected mode? It can be a security exception. Go to a IE settings and take a look if IFRAME isn't disabled.

Comment: No I am not running in protected mode.

Comment: Omg. Try running IE in normal mode in setting with lower security. Check if you haven't disabled iframes. But if a destination web page don't give you permission, that it can be in iframe. you cannot doit in anyway.